# Why is the role of the US president not more closely linked to the House of Representatives?

Tags: united-states, president, congress

It seems strange to me that the USA is currently in a state where its leader can't actually get much done on his own.... He isn't in control of either legislature, the House nor the Senate

In the UK and most other political systems, the leader of the country (the executive not the head of state) is elected by way of a majority in the legislature, which in practice makes him as powerful as his majority. If he loses power in the commons (representatives) he loses power overall, and a sustained imbalance is impossible. In the UK the upper house (Lords, roughly akin to the Senate) cannot stop a bill, only delay it. Therefore the UK is essentially a single tier legislature with safeguards.

What are the real benefits of having a directly elected president, such that they outweigh the uncertainty and in-fighting of having a president with no control in either legislature?

Comment: I'm torn between VTCing as duplicate of all the existing questions discussing separation of powers in USA, and downvoting for asking an absolutely trivial question thoroughly covered in Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_powers_under_the_United_States_Constitution

Comment: That relates to what powers are separated, and why (constitution) but doesn't discuss in anyway the effects... Nor does it explain why the president (despite having clearly delineated authority separate from the legislature) is directly elected rather than being elected via a majority in congress or whichever body

Comment: Also, all those wars US got involved in since 1945 says your "can't get much done" seems slightly inaccurate :)

Comment: The majority of those wars were undertaken while the president also had majorities in other areas, and there's a lot more to running a country than mere warfare.

Comment: Debatable. There's a strain of thought in Western politics that warfare should be pretty much the ONLY function of the federal government.

Comment: Western politics, or American? I've never seen such an attitude in Europe? Either way, that's very off topic

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the negative and positive consequences of a system of seperated powers?](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/what-are-the-negative-and-positive-consequences-of-a-system-of-seperated-powers)

Comment: Separated powers is different.... I'm not asking about the power separation, I'm asking about the disparity in when the two bodies are elected! We've seen examples of the president blocking the house, or the house blocking the president.... I'm asking about why the two aren't elected in unison

Comment: @JonStory the two being elected in unison defeat the whole purpose of separation of powers

Comment: point of detail: Presidents aren't (technically) elected by a direct vote. They are elected by the Electoral College: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electoral_College_(United_States)

Comment: @JonStory Incidentally, the strain of  ̶W̶e̶s̶t̶e̶r̶n̶   American thought DVK is referring to is [Libertarian Conservatism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libertarian_conservatism). An interesting [divergence](http://econlog.econlib.org/archives/2007/11/why_did_so_many.html) from classical anti-war libertarianism.

Comment: @LateralFractal - not quite. The isolationist faction of that (Ron Paul seems to fit) is pretty anti-war. They aren't PRO-military, they just say that anything other than military shouldn't be a federal government's scope at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Separation of powers is a common *justification* for this state of affairs but it does not really explain anything as such. Another way to look at it is that the US constitution is really old. The fact is that the idea was very popular at the time the US constitution was drafted and apparently influenced it greatly.

And the US was charting new territory, there wasn't much past experience to look back on. Even the very idea of a written constitution in the modern sense was kind of new (there were a few like Corsica but most European states didn't have one).

For most of the nineteenth century, the main issue with this constitution was not its presidential nature or its effectiveness in enacting legislation but the question of “states' rights”. For the most part, states' rights advocates were defeated and the constitution took such a symbolic value that tinkering with it or drafting a new one like many countries have done during the last century now seems all but impossible. Plus the US did not go through any major defeat, foreign occupation or authoritarian regime of the kind that prompted thorough changes in several European countries.

But if you read Montesquieu, separation of powers was not necessarily meant as rigidly as it was implemented in the US. The practical difficulties are numerous and modern constitutions tend to take a more nuanced approach (hence the apparent peculiarity of the US system compared to much of what came later). More recent constitutions also tend to be (much) longer than the US constitution.

In the US, it does kind of work however because the lower levels of government and the courts have a bigger role than in many other countries, including England (I am not writing “the UK” because the institutions of Scotland and Northern Ireland also have extensive powers).

Comment: Accepted for answering the question, rather than defending the system that the question was about, thank you!

Answer (score 10):

The inability of either branch to do things on their own is a feature, not a bug.

It's done that way on purpose to prevent any particular person or party from having too much control over the government

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_powers#United_States

Comment: But surely if the next presidential election returns a Republican, you'll have all the power with that party? I'm solely talking about the times when it's different - the majority of the time it seems to have been the same party in control of most or all of those bodies .... Eg when Obama was elected democrats had all 3. It just seems strange to elect them on different dates, so some years you have harmony, others conflict

Comment: It may have started as a feature but now it's a bug. As the first modern democracy (Corsica doesn't count as it only lasted 12 years) the United States had a lot prototype concepts. Some have worked out, some haven't. We forget that by today's standards, the founders weren't particularly confident in the principles of democracy. You only 'check' the power of the legislature and split off their executive powers if you don't trust the demos.

Comment: @JonStory - All the power might be with that party, but that doesn't mean that the President and Congress will agree.  Their overall goals will match better, but the way they want to accomplish things is different.  That said, it's a *lot* easier to pass legislation when you have both parts.  **That** said, if the people don't like what you do, they can vote you out of the House in 2 years.

Comment: "The inability of either branch to do things on their own" - that doesn't seem to be true, as GWB ursuped such a large amount of power for the executive branch ("I'll sign my own version of law, even if the congress voted it differently")..

Comment: @MartinSchröder: I am unaware of this. Can you direct me to specific resources and references to this event? I.e. Which bill did GWB sign into law that "the congress voted it differently"?

Comment: @sharur: See http://supreme.findlaw.com/legal-commentary/the-bush-administrations-adversarial-relationship-with-congress.html